# How to replace the first matching for each line with regular expression

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

Saying that I have such a file as below:

```
<random_string>hello<random_string>
random_string<random_string>hello<random_string>
```

I want to remove the first square bracket and its content so that the file becomes:

```
hello<random_string>
random_stringhello<random_string>
```

How could I achieve this?

I've tried to execute `:%s/<.*>//` but it will remove all things I think it's because it matches the last `>` for each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make regex matchers non-greedy?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-to-make-regex-matchers-non-greedy)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, as the other question assumes you know what "non-greedy" means, where as this one doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this would be the easiest solution:

```
%s/<[^>]*>//
```

It matches:

- `<` an opening angle bracket
- `[^>]*` anything not being a closing angle bracket
- `>` a angle bracket.

Of course the other solution is to use a non greedy operator as in the question linked by @Mass like this:

```
%s/<.\{-}>//
```