# Vim replace repeating pattern

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I got this repeating pattern, but when trying to replace it in vim like:
`%s/<pat>\_.*<\/pat>//` 
It will replace from first  to the very last .

How to replace these pattern by pattern?

My pattern is multline:

```
<pat>
asdfsadf
asdfasdf
asdfasdfddd
dsah
ghft
</pat>
<somethingelse>
...
<pat>
asdf
jhyj
dfg
</pat>
```

Comment: Welcome! Does https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-to-make-regex-matchers-non-greedy answer your question?